# MVC 5 Gmail API Integration

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm trying to use the GMail API in an MVC 5 project, but I seem to having difficulties on how to achieve that using the Owin Middleware for Authentication

I'm able to login via a Google account, and I can also get the user token as such

```
        var googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId =  "xxx",
            ClientSecret = "yyy",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
            Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = async ctx =>
                {
                    ctx.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:tokens:google:accesstoken", ctx.AccessToken));
                }
            },
        };
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);
```

I get the access token as I would expect, but Google Quicktart Tutorial [found here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-cs) seems to suggest a very different way to accomplish the Authentication

Is there a way I can use this AccessToken to create the objects required in the tutorial ?
Or are these two completely different?